# How to launch a "rogue" cli server as unprivileged user

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface

Let's state a situation:

- I have the possibility to run arbitrary commands on a server as an unprivileged user, through "unconventional means".
- I do not have the possibility to login using ssh to that server, either as my unprivileged user or anything else. So I do not have currently a CLI allowing me to run any commands I would like in a "normal" way.
- I can ping that server and nothing prevents me to connect to arbitrary ports.
- I still would like to have a command line to allow me to run arbitrary command as i wish on that server.

Theoretically nothing would prevent me to launch any program as my unprivileged user, including one that would open a port, allow some remote user to connect to it and just forward any commands to bash, returning the result. I just don't know any good program to do that.

So, does any one know? I looked at ways to launch ssh_server as an unprivileged user but some users reported that recent versions of ssh_server do not allow that anymore. Actually I don't even need ssh specifically, any way to get a working CLI would do the trick. Even a crappy node.js program launching an http server would work, as long as I have a CLI (... and it's not excessively crappy, the goal is to have a clean CLI, not something that bugs every two characters).

In case you would ask why I would like to do that, it's not related to anything illegal ^^. I just have to work with a very crappy Jenkins server for which I'm not allowed to have direct access to its agents. Whoever is responsible for that server doesn't give a sh** about its users' needs so we have to use hacky solutions just to have some diagnostic data about that server (like ram, cpu and disk usage, installed programs, etc...). Having a CLI that I can launch some time instead of altering a build configuration and waiting 20 minutes to have an answer about what's going on would really help.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds more like a workspace related issue to get the responsible persons involved to solve this issue?

Comment: Yeah, believe me when I say it's not how things work in a lot of big companies ^^. When your servers are outsourced you don't get the choice of your sysadmin, sometimes you don't even know who the hell he is or if there is even one. Not everyone works in a startup unfortunately.

Comment: Can you run anything through a jenkins build job?

Comment: Yes, absolutely anything. It's just basically a program that will execute shell scripts on a server. The only restrictions are that a) it runs scripts as an unprivileged user and b) it's really not practical for diagnosis of your server because you have to create your script, ask kindly that it's launched when the server have time to do it and wait patiently for the complete result to be displayed in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

So do you have shell access to the server at least once?  E.g., during the single day of the month when you are physically present at the site of your client or the outsourcing contractor?

And if you have shell access then, can you or your sysmin install [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/)?
It listens on port 9090.
You can then use the credentials of your local user and open a terminal window *in your browser*. See sidebar item "Terminal" on the screenshots of the [cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) homepage.

According to the [documentation](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/intro-cockpit)

> Cockpit has no special privileges and doesn’t run as root. It creates a session as the logged in user and has the same permissions as that user.

[image]

Comment: If I was able to have root access on that server I would just allow access through ssh, it would be way more efficient that anything else. Of course it's out of question.

Comment: Cockpit has no special privileges and doesn’t run as root. Maybe it can also be installed as a non-root user. It creates a session as the logged in user and has the same permissions as that user. - Another option is installing sshd as a non-root user and make it listen on some port > 1024. The documentation says it is possible (see `-h` option`)

Comment: I upvoted this because I wasn't aware of Cockpit, thanks for that tip!

Comment: The documentation explicitly say that you need root access in order to install it ( https://cockpit-project.org/running.html#ubuntu ). So, frankly, it's totally unrelated to the question I asked. Here you're trying to sell some kind of alternative to ssh to administer servers (it does more or less the same thing through a web browser). My question was "what if I don't have, and never will have, root access and I still want a possibility to launch a CLI ?".

Comment: Please forgive me for posting stuff irrelevant to your issue, but I started my answer with a somewhat cautious opening sentence. Seems that I've already helped someone else though.